# A Boolean ring in which if $2a=0$ then $a=0$

Tags: boolean-ring

In every Boolean ring we have $a^2=a$ for every $a$ in the ring. In some Boolean rings, if $2a=0$ then $a=0$. How to show this ring has just one member?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Boolean ring $2a=0$ for *every* $a$, so "for every $a$, if $2a=0$ then $a=0$" just means "for every $a$ one has $a=0$", which is what you wanted to prove.

To show that $2a=0$ always, do as egreg suggested: polarise $2a=(a+a)^2-2a^2=a+a-2a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $(a+a)^2=a+a$ implies $a+a=0$